# boto3 Glue get_job_runs results order

Tags: boto3, aws-glue

I'm using the boto3 glue client to get the most recent runs of a job using the get_job_runs method. It looks like the first result is the most recent, but can't find confirmation of this in the documentation. Does anyone have experience with this to confirm one way or the other?

Comment: yes it is because the same API used to list it under Glue jobs in Glue console. The same order is followed every where from latest to oldest.